# GridView hide Items area

Tags: .net, wpf, gridview

I want to hide the items area of a `GridView`, so that only the columns headers are visible. The part below the column headers should be invisible (collapsed).
Here is my futile attempt:

```
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="0" Visibility="Collapsed"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Size" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date"  />

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

So my question is, how can I hide the items area (the part below the column headers) of the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In listview, headers are shown using a GridViewHeaderRowPresenter. If you want to show only a header row, try to use this object in which you list the columns you need. With your example:

EDIT

```
//resources
<Window.Resources>
    <GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="HeaderColumns">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Size" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Date"  />
    </GridViewColumnCollection>
</Window.Resources>

//in layout
<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter  Columns="{StaticResource HeaderColumns}" />
```

HTH

Comment: hi michele, thanks for your answer. unfortunately it's not working. Firstly, I'm not sure what the all enclosing GridViewColumn is for. I removed that, but then I get an error that GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.Columns is null when the GridViewColumns are added to it. I tried it in XamlPad and in my program.

Comment: I've made some changes to the example.